# How to generate unique tag_id start from F-00001 in php

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

How to generate unique tag_id start from F-00001 when insert date into item table using php and mysql.

This is my my table. I have three columns in my database table using MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE item (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
tag_id VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: My question: Why do you need the id to be formatted in this way in the database?  I mean, why not use the autoincremented field and just adjust your queries and displaying when need be?  `str_pad()`ing an integer and prepending `F-` is a snap to do on the fly.  Save yourself the trouble.

Comment: @mickmackusa, first this is a small example of database table, my really data look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhmSa.jpg
So, I have tag column for item found and should have a unique F-(Number) in database that help to look on it in inventory easily.

Comment: Nick is a smart guy.  Listen to Nick.

Comment: I really like his way and work vary well thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mickmackusa points out, you don't need to have this field in your database as you can automatically generate it from your auto-increment `id` value. There are a number of ways to do this.

Use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) (MySQL 5.7 or later):

```
CREATE TABLE item (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
tag_id VARCHAR(8) AS CONCAT('F-', LPAD(id, 5, '0'))
)
```

Use a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html):

```
CREATE VIEW item_view AS 
SELECT *, CONCAT('F-', LPAD(id, 5, '0')) AS tag_id FROM item
```

Generate in PHP using [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
// assume $row is an associative array of row of table
$tag_id = 'F-' . str_pad($row['id'], 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```